# Does a crucible need to be fired in a kiln before use?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, metals

Say I made a crucible out of aluminum oxide primarily.  Won't it be fired by normal use of it or do you have to pre-fire it?  I understand they do that to get a consistent mass measurement.  But does it have to be done if you don't care about its mass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are carefull enough it is still necessary. This pre fire process can remove some low-boiling point substances, especially organic matter and moisture that may have been contaminated during transportation. In addition, pre-firing can also double-check for any defects in the crucible to ensure it does not crack during sample melting. Apart from using alumina, you can also try [boron nitride crucibles](https://www.qsrarematerials.com/boron-nitride-crucible-p-32.html), which have excellent thermal shock resistance. Although they are more expensive, they can be machined into any desired shape at any time.

Answer (score 2):

[Aluminum Oxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_oxide) is a ceramic and comes in bits and pieces, see the production process in the link.

[image: alumoxide]

How will you make it into a [crucible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crucible)?

[image: crucible]

if not by melting and pouring it into a form? The melting point is 2072C .

Generally clays also have to be fired to become stable, enter a phase tightly bound that only melting can destroy, or we would not have clay plates and cups. It is like asking to harden a teacup  from the potter's wheel by hot tea.

What is normal use for a crucible? To put some material for high temperature (lower than the melting point of the crucible). If the crucible has not been hardened the material contained in it will mix with the walls and make a mess instead of what was planned.